# Magento 2: Update Region/States dropdown for Specific Country

Tags: magento2, customer-account, country-regions

I want to add only Nigeria as the option in Country Dropdown, and the nigerian states in the states/province dropdown. How to do that.
I tried something through Admin panel, when i found these issues when i select US and nigeria and shown in the below screenshot.
https://prnt.sc/oicwpt
https://prnt.sc/oicyiz

How to avoid this?
I want only nigerian states to be in the dropdown.

Answer (score 3):

Basically Magento takes the list of regions/states from its own database. If you look into Magento database you would find two tables named *`directory_country_region`* and *`directory_country_region_name`*. `directory_country_region` is for adding states/regions and `directory_country_region_name` is for locale translations. By default Magento has regions only for few countries. If selected country has any region record in table then it appears as dropdown, else region area appears as input text.

So if you want to show states dropdown for Nigeria you need to enter records into these tables through script/query. Put `country_id` as **NG**. Please refer https://mage2-blog.com/magento-add-regions-to-country/ to know more about inserting states through query.

Hope it helps you.